# Can't apply plain HTML class to a Blazor component

Tags: html, razor, blazor

I've tried to use this code in my .NET 5 Blazor project, in .razor file:

```
<SignedLabel class="some-css-class" Price=123 Currency=Currency.Usd />
```

where `SignedLabel` - is a Blazor component and `Price`, `Currency` is the component's input parameters. I expect Blazor to treat the `class` word as an html property and apply the plain HTML class to this component so that I can style this component later on. But Blazor actually treats it as another input parameter for component and crashes whole app rendering with error:

```
Object of type 'SignedLabel' does not have a property matching the name 'class'
```

So the questions is

- Is it possible to use the class property in a such way?
- If yes, how should I do this?

PS: project settings:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>9</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    ...
</Project >
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot apply a class to a Component. You can use splatting to capture attributes placed on a Component to pass as parameter to one of the components elements.

`SomeComponent.razor`

```
<div @attributes="@CapturedAttributes">
    Hello
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string,object> CapturedAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

##### Usage

```
<SomeComponent id="fred" class="some-css-class" style="width:100vh" />
```

##### Will render:

```
<div id="fred" class="some-css-class" style="width:100vh" >
    Hello
</div>
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters)

Comment: I was going to complain that you can, too, apply classes by passing them as a variable-- but this answer is sexy!

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Its been available from the start. So many people over look it. It makes for very flexible components.

Comment: Yeah, I remember seeing that in Blazor University, but when I first went through that whole site, I didn't know enough to understand its significance.  I'm going to go through it all again and see what I missed.

Comment: I'd advise you to go through the Blazor docs and Chris Sainty's blog instead. That's what I've done.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to create a **Parameter** in your component. For example, this works fine. In a Tree component, **TopDivClass** parameter has been added an used.

In the markup of the component:

```
<div class="@TopDivClass">
```

In the code behind of the component:

```
[Parameter]
public string TopDivClass { get; set; }
```

In the markup using the component:

```
<Components.Tree TopDivClass="TreeView" />
```

The result in the HTML is

```
<div class="TreeView" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue and Google led me here, so I share it for anyone who might hit this as well.

My project setup is .NET 7 and Teams App project template (Blazor Server).

The problem was similar to OP's - I wanted to apply CSS class to Web Component. In my case it was [`FluentTextField`](https://brave-cliff-0c0c93310.azurestaticapps.net/TextField), so I couldn't modify its code.

Although doing this:

```html
<FluentTextField
    class="w-100"
    Placeholder="Provide the URL"
    Required="true"/>
```

wasn't producing any errors and in browser Dev Tools I could see the class added the element, i.e. `<fluent-text-field class='w-100'>`, the CSS defined in parent component wasn't applied.

Turns out, it's enough to change "Blazor syntax" to "JS syntax" and everything works fine:

```html
<fluent-text-field
    class="w-100"
    Placeholder="Provide the URL"
    Required="true"/>
```